# How to use date type field in kendo ui Javascript in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker

I am create one sample application and use kendo-ui inline editing grid.

**Problem is**: not come date field value in action controller.

**View page Code is:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {


        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                type: "json",
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("CriticalDateList", "Home"))",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json"  
                    },

                    create: {
                        url: "@Html.Raw(Url.Action("InsertCriticalDate", "Home"))",
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: "json"
                    },
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    if (e.action == "itemchange") {
                        e.items[0].dirtyFields = e.items[0].dirtyFields || {};
                        e.items[0].dirtyFields[e.field] = true;
                    }
                },
      batch: true,
                        schema: {
                            data: "Data",
                            total: "Total",
                            errors: "Errors",
                            model: {
                                id:"Id",
                                fields: {
                                    Id: { editable: false},
                                    Date: { editable: true, type: "date" },

                                }
                            }

                        },

                        error: function (e) {
                            //display_kendoui_grid_error(e);
                            this.cancelChanges();
                        },
                        pageSize:5,
                        serverPaging: true,
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        serverSorting: true
                    },
                        pageable: true,
                        height: 500,
                        toolbar: ["create"],
                        columns: [

                            {field: "Date", title: "Date", format: "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}", parseFormats: ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zz"], width: "130px"},
                            { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Action", width: "250px" }],
                        editable: "inline"

                    });
```

**Action Code is:**

```
    public ActionResult InsertCriticalDate(CriticalDateModels model)
    {
        return null;
    }
```

**output is.**

[image]

**And in my action i am getting different date.**

[image]

Comment: Post a complete script... your script is missing data source..

Comment: ya its half script because no need to make full script here because some times long explanation is reason for down possibilities for answer. if you want to see full script then i will update it.